# Как удалить все выбранные значения в config.ini через listBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как удалить только выбранные или все выбранные значения через `listBox` в файле `config.ini`. Текущий код удаляет выбранные значения только в `listBox`, не получается сделать связку для удаления всех выбранных значений и в файле `config.ini`.

Используется класс `IniFile.cs` подробнее: [link](https://gist.github.com/DamianSuess/e8bf4679b201e07757e97aad944e0395)

Содержимое файла `config.ini` выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где `value 01-02-03` это `patch`, а `[GUID]` обозначает имя секции в файле `config.ini`.

Ниже представлен код, в котором работает удаление только одной выделенной строки, и в `listBox`, и в файле `config.ini` (еще ниже, удаление всех значений только в `listBox`)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Выделение нескольких элементов в listBox через (CTRL или SHIFT)
    listBoxPatch.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
}
private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var patch = listBoxPatch.GetItemText(listBoxPatch.SelectedItem);
    var readPatch = ini.Read(patch, "GUID"); // Получение значений из файла config.ini
    ini.DeleteKey(patch, "GUID"); // Удаление выбранной строки в файле config.ini

    RemoveSubName(readPatch); // Удаление раздела в реестре по выбранному значению

    // Удаление выбранных или всех выбранных значений в listBox
    var r = listBoxPatch.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
    foreach (string s in r)
        listBoxPatch.Items.Remove(s);
}
```

Что из себя представляет приложение - в поле `textBoxPatch` прописывается значение и добавляется в `listBoxPatch`, значение записывается в файл `config.ini`, создается раздел реестра и добавляется ключ с этим значением.

Для наглядности, если выбрать все три значения в `listBox` и нажать `Удалить`, то файле `config.ini` удалится только одно из выбранных значений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте удалять записи из файла и реестра таким же образом, как удаляете записи из `ListBox`:

```
//более «говорящие» наименования
var patchesToDelete = listBoxPatch.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
foreach (string patch in patchesToDelete ) 
{
    var readPatch = ini.Read(patch, "GUID"); 
    ini.DeleteKey(patch, "GUID"); 
    RemoveSubName(readPatch);

    listBoxPatch.Items.Remove(patch);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Идеально подходит, только в строке `listBoxPatch.Items.Remove(patch);` вместо `(s)` > `(patch)`

Comment: @Vitokhv Пожалуйста! Поправил.